# What are the beneifts of using a database abstraction layer?

Tags: dbal

I've been using some code that implements the phpBB DBAL for some time. Recently I had to implement a more full package around it and decided to use the DBAL throughout. In the main, it's been OK. But occassionally there are circumstances where I can't see the logic in using it. It seems to make the simple much more complicated.

What benefits does a DBAL offer rather then writing sql statements directly?

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) :

API level abstraction

Libraries like OpenDBX unify access to databases by providing a single low-level programming interface to the application developer. **Their advantages are most often speed and flexibility because they are not tied to a specific query language (subset) and only have to implement a thin layer to reach their goal**. The application developer can choose from all language features but has to provide configurable statements for querying or changing tables. Otherwise his application would also be tied to one database.

Answer (score 1):

When cooking a dish, you do not want several chefs having access to the pot.  They could all be adding spices unaware that another chef had already added a spice.  Ideally, you want a single chef that would serve as a single point of access to avoid spoiling the soup.

The same with databases.  A single point of access can avoid problems of multiple services accessing the data in different ways.

Comment: I like your analogy but I don't fully get the 'single point of access'. Do you mean by always coding the database queries in the same format?

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, updating.  If two tables needed to be updated, one process could lock table A and wait for table B, another process could lock table B and wait for table A...Deadlock!  If both processes use the same update code, this will never happen.

Comment: Interesting. I'll check the phpBB DBAL and see how much it's doing 'behind the scenes'. Thanks.